# Newbie snowboarding options a couple of days not too far from Stockholm

Tags: sweden, stockholm, winter-sports

We have been to [Romme](http://www.rommealpin.se/) twice to learn and get better at snowboarding. We have spent 4 days each time and plan to do the same this season. What are the best places to do this where you can drive and manage to spend a decent amount of time in the pist even the first day. We would like something as good as Romme and probably a bit further (since I am pretty sure there are nothing better closer) but still possible to drive there in the morning, get some skiing, stay 3 nights and drive home after the last day of skiing. It should be a bit varied technically since we are getting better.... but the more advanced slopes are off limits. (We can manage the "red" ones in Romme but not the "black" ones.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 main alternatives that are as close to Stockholm as Romme.

[Kungsberget](http://www.kungsberget.se/) outside of Sandviken in Gästrikland:

- 210 kms from Stockholm
- 11 ski lifts
- 18 runs

[Bjursås](http://www.bjursas.com/) north of Falun in Dalarna:

- 250 kms from Stockholm
- 7 ski lifts
- 21 runs

[Säfsen](http://www.safsen.se/) in the south west corner of Dalarna:

- 270 kms from Stockholm
- 6 ski lifts
- 16 runs

A bit further is [Branäs](http://www.branas.se/) in the north of Värmland - may be interesting if coming from Gothenburg:

- 440 kms from Stockholm
- 16 ski lifts
- 34 runs

All these places got varying runs and one or more aerial lifts (useful for snow board beginners). Kungsberget is closest to Stockholm and probably the best alternative to Romme but Bjursås seems pretty good too.

Answer (score 3):

If distance wasn't an issue, [Åre](http://www.skistar.com/en/Are/Skiing/Pistemap/) would be the way to go. It's one of the best Swedish ski resorts, with more than 100 runs, varying from green to black. Unfortunately, it's situated in Jämtland, and is a good 530 km away from Stockholm, so probably not going to be your first choice.

Somewhat closer is [Sälen](http://www.skistar.com/salen/), which also sports more than a 1[00 tracks of varying difficulty](http://www.skistar.com/en/Salen/Skiing/Piste-maps/), including more advanced runs and freeriding. It's very popular among tourists, and can get crowded in peak season. It's slightly closer to Stockholm, around 430 km, and Google Maps says it would take around 5 hours to get there.

[Idre Fjäll](http://www.idrefjall.se/) in Dalarna is somewhat family-friendly and recommended for new and intermediate boarders, as it has [40-ish](http://www.idrefjall.se/trail+map__.html) tracks, most of them green or blue. You'll have to travel around 450 km to get there.

If reliable snowfall is going to be an issue (not likely, if SMHI is to be trusted), then you might want to try [Funäsfjällen](http://www.funasfjallen.se/) resorts -- they claim to have very reliable snow coverage. There are a [few different skiing areas](http://www.funasfjallen.se/vinter/allt-om-funaesfjaellen/) to choose from, with varying slope length and difficulty. Unfortunately, it's even farther than Åre, almost 600 km away from Stockholm.

<sub>There are some smaller hills nearer to Stockholm, such as [Hammarbybacken](http://www.skistar.com/sv/Hammarbybacken/skidakning/), but with only a few tracks, they are only good for a one-day trip.</sub>

---

All being said, it might not be possible to get to any of these if starting in the morning and hoping to score a run on the same day (you know how short the day is in the winter in Sweden, especially up north). If I were to choose, I'd go with Idre Fjäll, as it is closest and somewhat newbie-friendly, with Åre as a solid backup choice.

Comment: yeah - the hills of stockholm is not worth trying. We live close to väsjöbacken but has never been there. Idre is a bit too far away for a 4-day trip.

Comment: There are [seasonal overnight trains](http://www.veolia-transport.se/tmpl/ExtensionPage____45989.aspx?epslanguage=ML) to Åre from Stockholm, but will set you back at least 550 SEK/person one-way, and this is probably more than you'd like to spend on travelling.

Comment: The length of the day isn't really relevant as all ski slopes worth speaking of have floodlights until very late at night. I live in Jämtland and have been to Åre, Funäsfjällen, and so on, and usually they are open until at least 10PM in the high season.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Åre or Funäsfjällen are really so far away as to be impossible. I've driven from where I live (Östersund) to Stockholm several times and it usually takes 5 hours or so. If I start driving at 9AM I'm usually there by 3-4PM.

Considering that the slopes usually close at 9-10PM or even later in some areas, that's plenty of time for a quick shower, some dinner, and a few hours of skiing before you have to sleep.

And for me at least it's worth the extra couple of hours driving to have access to a real ski resort with a lot of different tracks to choose from.

Comment: If spending a week I think it is fine but to spend two half days in the car for 3 full days and 1 half day of skiing is not worth it. (Plus you may not be that good a driver after skiing a full day and then driving for 5 hours.)

Comment: Agree with @froderik, plus you might run into some serious traffic issues on the roads if you pick the wrong time to go.

Answer (score 2):

I went snowboarding in [Stöten](http://stoten.se/), It's a nice small ski area but it seems a bit to far from Stockholm.

Answer (score 2):

One of the closest would be [Flottsbro](http://www.flottsbro.se/) 23.4 km or 21 minutes by car from central Stockholm. It has a vertical drop of 103 meters and the longest slope is 700 meters. It has five runs and jumps for skiing and snowboarding.